# Bootstrap collapse start open/collapsed depending on CheckBox value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

A form contains some checkbox and a `div` area which should be collapsed or visible depending on the checkbox value. I am using Bootstrap 3.

While toggeling the `div` when the checkbox state changes is no problem I was able to find out, how to start the `div` in the correct state:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someCheckbox">

<div id="collapseContainer">
    ...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $collapseContainer = $('#collapseContainer');
    $collapseContainer.collapse({
        toggle: true    // THIS HAS NO EFFECT
    });

    var $checkbox = $('#someCheckbox');
    $checkbox.change(function() { 
        // Toggle the Container when CheckBox is clicked
        $collapseContainer.collapse('toggle');
    }); 

    if ($checkbox.is(':checked') == false) {
        // Solution from other thread - DOES NOT WORK
        $collapseContainer.removeClass('in');
    //}
</script>
```

The answers to similar question suggest to remove the `in` class manually to set to `collapsed` state but this does not work. It seems that the applying the plugin starts an animation which only adds the `in` class when it completes. Thus the `in` is not present when checking the initial state of the checkbox.

**How to solve this?**

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify this: If the **checkbox is checked** when the page is loaded, the div should start as **expanded**. If the **checkbox is not checked** the div should be **collapsed**.

In my tests adding the `toggle: true` option to the plugin call made absolutely no difference.

---

EDIT 2:

I have use the answer by @pc_coder to build the following, simple HTML file. While the snippet in his answer seem to work just perfect, the HTML version does not. The only difference between `checkbox1` and `checkbox2` is, that nr. 2 is visible immediately while checkbox1 animates in. But the actual goal, that nr. 1 is hidden and nr. 2 is visible does not work.

One difference to the snippet is, that I put all code in `$(document).ready`. If I leave the setup code outside, it does not work at all.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">         
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                var $checkbox = $('#someCheckbox');
                var $checkbox2 = $('#someCheckbox2');

                var $collapseContainer = $('#collapseContainer');
                var $collapseContainer2 = $('#collapseContainer2');

                $checkbox.change(function() { 
                    $collapseContainer.collapse('toggle');
                }); 

                $checkbox2.change(function() { 
                    $collapseContainer2.collapse('toggle');
                });

                $collapseContainer.collapse($checkbox.prop('checked') ? "show" : "hide");
                $collapseContainer2.collapse($checkbox2.prop('checked') ? "show" : "hide");
            }); 
        </script>

        <input type="checkbox"checked id="someCheckbox" />
        <div id="collapseContainer" >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="someCheckbox2" />

        <div id="collapseContainer2" class="collapse">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do u want to start as collepsed or expanded? Because toggle is already true as default

Comment: The initial collapsed/expanded state should depend on the initial checkbox value. I have edited the question to make this more clear. using the toggle option seem to have no effect.

Comment: I added answer . You can check it @Andrei Herford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In collaption There are three types `toggle`(which is default true),`show`,`hide`
As beginning, you can use one if close to check checkbox then show hide depend of its situation. If you want to see when page loaded so you need to put it in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $collapseContainer.collapse($checkbox.prop('checked') ? "show" : "hide");
 });
```

```js
var $collapseContainer = $('#collapseContainer');
var $collapseContainer2 = $('#collapseContainer2');
var $checkbox2 = $('#someCheckbox2');

$checkbox2.change(function() { 
    $collapseContainer2.collapse('toggle');
}); 

var $checkbox = $('#someCheckbox');
$checkbox.change(function() { 
  $collapseContainer.collapse('toggle');
}); 

$(document).ready(function() {
   $collapseContainer.collapse($checkbox.prop('checked') ? "show" : "hide");
   $collapseContainer2.collapse($checkbox2.prop('checked') ? "show" : "hide");
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox"checked id="someCheckbox" />
<div id="collapseContainer" class="collapse" >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
</div>
    
<input type="checkbox" id="someCheckbox2" />

<div id="collapseContainer2" class="collapse" >
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,        
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was still not able to get it running. While your snippet works fine a HTML version I created does not. See ma 2nd edit for details.

Comment: in html you missed to add classes to conatiners in html and one of your checbox.change function has syntax error u missed } before ) . https://jsfiddle.net/7xdw3j50/